# How to fill in missing values in a panel data set

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame where each row summarises the monthly activity of forum members, including the number of posts, the number of replies, the number of hateful posts and the number of hateful replies they receive. It looks like this:

| post_month | user_name | thread_posts | hate_posts | replies | hateful_replies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01 | !ronman | 11 | 4 | 19 | 6 |
| 2018-02 | !ronman | 43 | 11 | 138 | 39 |
| 2018-04 | !ronman | 51 | 16 | 169 | 57 |
| 2020-06 | $toneman | 111 | 37 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-07 | $toneman | 141 | 33 | 23 | 9 |
| 2020-09 | $toneman | 65 | 14 | 0 | 0 |
| 2020-10 | $toneman | 13 | 0 | 4 | 0 |

However, notice in the post_month column that sometimes the rows skip a month if the forum member was inactive for that period. Hence, I wish to populate these absent months with rows that contain the relevant month in the post_month column and populate 0's in every other column (apart from username).

Desired output is something like this:

| post_month | user_name | thread_posts | hate_posts | replies | hateful_replies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01 | !ronman | 11 | 4 | 19 | 6 |
| 2018-02 | !ronman | 43 | 11 | 138 | 39 |
| 2018-03 | !ronman | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2018-04 | !ronman | 51 | 16 | 169 | 57 |
| 2020-06 | $toneman | 111 | 37 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-07 | $toneman | 141 | 33 | 23 | 9 |
| 2020-08 | $toneman | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2020-09 | $toneman | 65 | 14 | 0 | 0 |
| 2020-10 | $toneman | 13 | 0 | 4 | 0 |

What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: kindly post the expected output dataframe

Comment: apologies! have edited the Q now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would convert the `post_month` to datetime, then set dataframe index by it and use `.asfreq()` to fill the missing parts:

```py
df["post_month"] = pd.to_datetime(df["post_month"])
df = df.set_index("post_month")

df = df.groupby("user_name", group_keys=False).apply(
    lambda x: (x := x.asfreq("MS")).assign(user_name=x["user_name"].ffill()).fillna(0)
).reset_index()
df['post_month'] = df['post_month'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  post_month user_name  thread_posts  hate_posts  replies  hateful_replies
0    2018-01   !ronman          11.0         4.0     19.0              6.0
1    2018-02   !ronman          43.0        11.0    138.0             39.0
2    2018-03   !ronman           0.0         0.0      0.0              0.0
3    2018-04   !ronman          51.0        16.0    169.0             57.0
4    2020-06  $toneman         111.0        37.0      1.0              1.0
5    2020-07  $toneman         141.0        33.0     23.0              9.0
6    2020-08  $toneman           0.0         0.0      0.0              0.0
7    2020-09  $toneman          65.0        14.0      0.0              0.0
8    2020-10  $toneman          13.0         0.0      4.0              0.0
```

Comment: yes!! this has worked a charm - thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df = pd.read_clipboard()
# convert post_month to Period
df['post_month'] = df.post_month.apply(pd.Period, freq='M')

# create a dictionary to contain the range of periods from beginning to end per group:
new_data = {'post_month': lambda f: pd.period_range(f.min(), f.max(), freq='M')}

# show the missing rows, and fill the nulls with 0:
df.complete(new_data, by='user_name', fill_value = 0)

  post_month user_name  thread_posts  hate_posts  replies  hateful_replies
0    2018-01   !ronman            11           4       19                6
1    2018-02   !ronman            43          11      138               39
2    2018-03   !ronman             0           0        0                0
3    2018-04   !ronman            51          16      169               57
4    2020-06  $toneman           111          37        1                1
5    2020-07  $toneman           141          33       23                9
6    2020-08  $toneman             0           0        0                0
7    2020-09  $toneman            65          14        0                0
8    2020-10  $toneman            13           0        4                0
```